# What is the observed loglikelihood function from EM

Tags: expectation-maximization, mixture-distribution

I am studying EM algorithm. I would like to use it to estimate model parameters. I just wonder what is the returned log likelihood function for my model. Is it the complete log likelihood function or the incomplete log likelihood function? That is, I would like to show the value of log likelihood of my model. Also, I would like to use AIC and BIC. However, I do not know what is the function that I need to calculate for AIC and BIC.

Do I need to use this function:

$$ \sum_{j} z_{1,j} [\log(\pi_1) + \log(f(x_j;\Psi^\text{old}_1))] + \sum_{j} z_{2,j} [\log(\pi_2) + \log(f(x_j;\Psi^\text{old}_2))]$$

to calculate AIC and BIC or I must use this one:

$$ [log(\pi_1) + \log(f(x_j;\Psi_1))] + [\log(\pi_2) + \log(f(x_j;\Psi_2)]$$

Any help please?

Comment: What do you mean by "returned log likelihood function"? The likelihood used in AIC and BIC is the observed log likelihood function

Comment: I mean what the loglikelihood function should be returned by model. That is, if I would like to calculate the values of the logliklihhod of my model. Then how can I calculate it. Do i need to use the complete logliklihood function?

Comment: @Xi'an, yes what is the observed function. is it the incomplete or the complete one. is it this function: `mysum(tau*(log(pi1)+log(dnorm(dat,mu1,sigma1))))+mysum(tau*(log(pi2)+log(dnorm(dat,mu2,sigma2))))`

Comment: Neither form is correct you must use the observed log likelihood function